# Convergence of sample central moments

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

> **Convergence of sample central moments**
>   Let there be $\{X_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$, a set of iid r.v.'s with $\mathbb{E}(X_{i}) = \mu_{i}$ and  $\mathbb{E}(\lvert X_{i} \rvert^{k}) < \infty$. Defining $\mu_{k} = \mathbb{E}((X_{i}-\mu)^{k})$ and $M_{k} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{k}$. Show that $M_{k} \xrightarrow[]{P} \mu_{k}$.

I found the following question about assymptotically unbiasedness that partially helped me with my doubt. However my goal is differente.

[Central sample moments are asymptotically unbiased](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059303/central-sample-moments-are-asymptotically-unbiased)

My thoughts are using the binomial theorem as he did to show that each $(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{k}$ converge to a certain value and thus the sum divided by $n$ will converge by the weak law of large numbers. I'd appreciate some insights. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the binomial formula, 
$$
M_{n,k}-\mu_k=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom kj\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i^j\left(-\overline{X}\right)^{k-j}-\mathbb E\left[X_i^j\left(-\overline{X}\right)^{k-j}\right]\right)
$$
hence it suffices to show that for all $j\in\left\{0,\dots,k\right\}$, 
$$
\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i^j \overline{X} ^{k-j}-\mathbb E\left[X_i^j \overline{X}^{k-j}\right]\right)\to 0\mbox{ a.s.}
$$
Observe that by the weak law of large numbers, $\overline{X}\to \mu$ in probability hence we are reduced to show that 
$$
\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i^j \mu^{k-j}-\mathbb E\left[X_i^j \overline{X}^{k-j}\right]\right)\to 0\mbox{ a.s.}
$$
Applying the weak law of large numbers to the i.i.d. sequence $\left(X_i^j\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$, we are reduces to prove that 
$$
\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E\left[X_i^j \overline{X}^{k-j}\right]=\mathbb E\left[X_1^j\right]\mu^{k-j}.
$$
Write $Y_{i,n}:=n^{-1}\sum_{l=1,l\neq i}^nX_l$. Then it remains to show that 
$$
\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E\left[X_i^j \left(\overline{X}^{k-j}-Y_{i,n}^{k-j}\right)\right]\to 0.$$